# designing a web application with future compatibility to cloud

Tags: sql-server, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, cloud, azure-sql-database

I'm about to create/design a multi tenant web app for an upcoming project for a client. Though I wanted to use the `azure cloud/sql server`, unfortunately I can't do this for the first phase (may be an upgrade in a couple of years). So currently the web app will be self hosted at both the server and database level.

The architecture will be pretty standard, `asp.net MVC5, WebAPI, DDD, Dapper,SQL 2014` etc. I'm going `async` with dapper to SQL as well which enables me to do `async` all the way from `MVC` layer. The `database` will have partitions at tenant level.

As mentioned, I'll want to move the whole app to azure cloud in future so I can scale the application better.

My question is whether I can do anything right now with my design to help this migration in future, assuming there is no infrastructure dependencies in the code and modules are loosely coupled etc, OR the cloud architecture is so different that I'll have to change a lot of things around when the time comes?

I understand the database layer will change to work with `SQL azure` but any other changes than that?

Comment: Unfortunately this question is kinda broad (and opinion-soliciting). No real right answer here. It's a great discussion question though (maybe quora?), talking through cloud migration friction points and considerations...

Answer (score 0):

We have moved a couple of simple web sites and created some new ones in Azure. We've had to make no architectural changes to existing legacy apps to make them cloud service web roles. I was actually quite amazed at how easy the initial moves over to Azure Web Roles has went.

The biggest coding type issue has been getting used to not being able to update web.config and the new cloud service config without a redeployment of your sites. Moving any of your 'configurable' web.config settings into the appsettings section of the web.config would be a suggestion, allowing you to update the settings via the portal.

If you require custom, non OOB, IIS settings it will require code or scripting that is pretty easy to implement. We've ran into a few issues with security related to accessing on prem 'legacy' stuff like file shares. No show stoppers just had to fight with lack of documentation and the infrastructure team that is not to hip on cloud stuff.

Overall our biggest issue by far has been with lack of documentation and direction from the cloud service vendor and we are actually growing more and more frustrated with a blatant lack of enterprise level support that we are used to getting from said vendor. They provide plenty of simple examples and hi level documentation but little real meat that you will need unless you are doing very simple sites and deployments. Much can be done with low level API calls and scripting but this is a nightmare to try and keep up with.

Comment: The question itself is broad-and opinion-based, and should be closed. Your answer includes your subjective issues, opinions and complaints about a company, which don't belong here.

Comment: @David, I removed the reference to the company you work for. Yes there are some complaints but anyone should be concerned with such complaints if they want to use the platform.

Comment: You missed the point. Even if the OP's question were on-topic, this is a *programming Q&A site* with answers that are objective. Again, not the place for rants about issues you've personally had with support.